# Servlet resource is not available HTTP 404

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I got a servlet, which I'm trying to get to through a hyperlink. 
I checked the Servlet's folder availability by a hyperlink to JSP file on that folder.
I also checked the Servlet itself when asking it on the hyperlink with the `.java` extension, and I got
the code of that Servlet on the browser.

When I'm trying to connect to that Servlet either to `doGet` or `doPost`, I'm getting a 404 HTTP error,
the resource is not available.

*Web.xml:*

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controllers.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/controllers</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/views/welcomePage.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What URL did you enter in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

As you post in your question

> I also checked the Servlet itself when asking it on the hyperlink with the .java extension

I think you are putting the servlet class file in a folder under your web folder and that is why you can access trough the url.

```
project
   src
   web
     controllers
       TestServlet.java
     page.jsp
     WEB-INF
       classes
```

As opposed of the jsp files the servlet classes must be in the WEB-INF/classes folder (the .class file not the .java file), and the source code of your class must be in the `src` folder of your project under the package controllers so:

```
project
   src
     controllers
       TestServlet.java
   web     
     page.jsp
     WEB-INF
       classes
          controllers
            TestServlet.class
```

If you're using eclipse, netbeans or other IDE when you put your java class in the source folder it automatically put the .class in the WEB-INF/classes folder.

Answer (score 0):

You map your servlet to the URL pattern **/controllers** - so your post should go to `http://localhostOrWhatever/maybeYourWebAppDirectoryDependingOnSetup/controllers`

Comment: Where do you know this is actually the OP's problem?

Comment: @msrd0 "when asking it on the hyperlink with the .java extension, and i got the code of that servlet on the browser." - sounds like the URL he's trying to use to access his servlet is incorrect to me

Comment: It seems like the OP uses the `file://` protocoll, but I think the question is very unclear at the moment

Comment: I believe my answer solves the issue of him not being able to access a resource as it provides explanation on how to access a servlet properly ...

Comment: lets see, the OP is the onliest one that can decide this